# Website New navigation "That's a miss" error on initial "question" navigation

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

On occasion since enabling the new navigation when going from "Dashboard" to "Questions" link, I get the following screen:

[image: That's a miss]

Note that this is the default page hit for me when navigating to "questions" it just seems that the filters are perhaps not being applied correctly on initial hit?  If I refresh the page all is well.  I have noticed the error only seems to occur if I haven't hit the questions tab for several minutes, and there is usually a noticeable delay before I get the image (in comparison to when the questions successfully load)

Update
It seems that it can happen from other areas not just "Dashboard".  I waited ~10 minutes from the questions tab and hit the tab again and experienced that issue.

Anyone else experience this?  Is there a place that this should be reported?

Comment: Never ever saw that...

Comment: You are hitting an empty cache: this is like the old nav, with the difference that there are very few users on the new nav, so this happens to a higher percent of people.

Comment: @Sklivvz Seems like [my case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259346/284991). Or not?

Comment: I'm getting this occasionally too - seems intermittent.

Comment: @Sklivvz I'm getting this message with increasing regularity now. It seems to be specifically when it's attempting to get the "need answers" tab. Happens so often now, I'm considering turning it off.

Comment: Happens basically every single time now to me when I open up SO for the first time for the day with the new navigation.

Comment: Happened to me several times in the past hour with http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=new&tagFilter=all

Comment: This happens to me as well, with multiple search instances but mostly when searching for new questions. I've also had the problem of new Questions hanging for a bit while waiting for response. Usually either a reload or just waiting a few second, though this gives me "That's a miss", fixes this

Comment: The underlying issue (the SQL query executed when the cache is empty being slow) has been around for quite some time now, but the new feature testing just made it more visible.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Then I suggest changing the error message `Sorry, that filter combination has no results. Please try different criteria.` is certainly not what is happening.

Comment: I'm getting this *most times* when going to the all questions tab, and this has only been noticeable since last Friday

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wouldn't it make sense to address the underlying issue then? Or adjust the tolerance for the SQL query to come back?

Comment: @RowlandShaw: Of course it does; I'm just mentioning that the devs are aware there is this performance issue.

Comment: @Sklivvz You guys need to place a link on that page pointing to this question.  The number of questions relating to this error on meta is too damn high! (insert image of the rent is too damn high guy here)

Comment: We're addressing a bit of tag engine perf next iteration (due in a few days). That is the core issue, but it's not trivially solved. There's a cache around the results, which is why you get results when you refresh, and why outside of alpha most people don't notice.

Comment: This happens for me almost every other time reloading the Questions page for me.

Comment: This really needs to get fixed. It's showing up two times out of three, sometimes when I'm going to the next page of questions. So annoying!!!

Comment: Like [jmoerdyk](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297688/website-new-navigation-thats-a-miss-error-on-initial-question-navigation#comment218345_297688) I'm getting it quite regularly and all it takes to click on `Questions` one more time to get a normal screen.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - It's not just a performance issue, but also  **annoyance**.  It should be tagged as `bug`.

Comment: @PM77-1 I had it originally tagged as such, but the tag bug was edited out.

Comment: heh heh.  I was just thinking I hadn't gotten this for a few days.  Now I'm ***only*** getting it (at least for the last several minutes)

Comment: I get this if I'm on e.g. page 2 of all questions for a tag and then I click something like bounties (where bounties <= pageSize) . There's only 1 page of bounties, but the page=2 is still in the URL, therefore the request fails.

Comment: @Sklivvz - I take it you know "That's a miss" is still happening: http://imgur.com/Nc0eosf url was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest&tags=or%20or%20or%20or%20or%20or%20or%20or%20or%20or%20or%20or%20or%20or%20or%20powershell%20powershell-4.0%20powershell-hosting%20powershell-ise%20powershell-jobs%20powershell-module%20powershell-provider%20powershell-remoting%20powershell-sdk%20powershell-studio%20powershell-v1.0%20powershell-v2.0%20powershell-v3.0%20powershell-v4.0%20powershell-v5.0%20powershell-workflow&mode=any&pageSize=50

Answer (score 1):

We've done a lot of perf work on tag engine with the last release. While I can't rule out timeouts, hopefully things should be noticeably better now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and should be fixed.

@[Sklivvz](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7028/sklivvz) [said on 8th of July](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297688/website-new-navigation-thats-a-miss-error-on-initial-question-navigation#comment218323_297688):

> We're addressing a bit of tag engine perf next iteration (due in a few days). That is the core issue, but it's not trivially solved. There's a cache around the results, which is why you get results when you refresh, and why outside of alpha most people don't notice.

So, hopefully this is in progress right now.