# Wildcard question lists sometimes fail to load

Tags: bug, question-lists, error-message

I have the wildcard tag `css*` favourited. Sometimes when I click on it, rather than being greeted by the normal set of (over 350,000) questions, I instead get:

> [image: 0 questions]
>
> [image: That's a miss!]

There are no JavaScript errors and as new questions with tags matching the wildcard filter are created I see them appear one by one.

As an active SO user I see this once or twice per day. Refreshing the page resolves the issue:

> [image: Lots of questions...]
>
> [image: That's not a miss!]

I'm really not sure what's causing it. Emptying my cache and reloading the page doesn't recreate the issue. I've also had it happen whilst actively using the site (e.g. clicking on my `css*` favourite tag, loading the question list, clicking on a question, doing a few other things, then clicking on `css*` again to find the questions have disappeared).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Website New navigation "That's a miss" error on initial "question" navigation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297688/website-new-navigation-thats-a-miss-error-on-initial-question-navigation) Not an exact duplicate, but same bug it seems.

Comment: @JonasCz I'm not sure if that's the same problem. That seems to affect the overall questions list, not a tag-filtered list. Also the answer seems to imply that that particular problem has been fixed.