# Filter combination sometimes fail with new navigation - "That's a miss"

Tags: discussion, support, new-nav, tag-filters

Related question : [Website New navigation "That's a miss" error on initial "question" navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297688/website-new-navigation-thats-a-miss-error-on-initial-question-navigation)

But I don't think my question is duplicate of that question as that topic talks about the issue with the default page hit. And I do not see any filters actually shown in the screenshot.

I have a combination of **tags** as `OR` conditions used to **filter** questions. They are basically combination of all tags related to [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle).

Sometimes, it fails to apply the filter. See the screenshot:

[image]

It's not that it *always* fails, but it is happening too *frequently*. I need to either refresh the page or edit my tags(not exactly edit the tags, but just move the cursor) and it would load the questions.

**For example:**

[image]

Is it something related to my local cache? Do I need to fix something with my browser settings?

**What I do as a workaround:**

- Either **refresh the page**
- Or **edit the tags**(not exactly edit the tags, but just move the cursor)

and it would load the questions.

But, is there a permanent fix to this? Or am I left only with the workaround?

Comment: Wait a minute... Did you just edit an answer into your question?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Well I just described properly. Since there is actually no particular resolution, but a workaround. Is it bad? Feel free to edit. If it improves the question, it is always welcome :-)

Comment: Answers should not be written into questions; they should be posted as answers. Either as your own self-answer, or (and this is what I just did for you) as a clarifying edit to an existing answer; in this case, the one you accepted.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I am not at all advocating that answers should be included in the question itself. If you re-read my question, I have just included a cause and the workaround which I have had been doing. So, where is the confusion here? I am confident that the cause and workaround which are already stated by me, are actually are a part of the question. The answer which I accepted just confirmed my steps, and that is evident in the comments of the accepted answer. Makes sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Cause:**

This is happening because the page finished loading before the server can finish retrieving the data from the database. As your search gets larger with more and more 'or' operators, the query gets more and more complex, which results in longer loading times on the server.

**Workaround:**

Refresh the page. The next time you load that same page (/search), the query will be cached by the server, allowing it to respond in time.

As an alternative to pressing the reload button, move the cursor as if you were editing the tags in your query; this will do a reload.

**Related:**

[Getting a lot of blank pages but refresh fixes it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305734/getting-a-lot-of-blank-pages-but-refresh-fixes-it)
[Why do I have to reload to see any questions for a search?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271287/why-do-i-have-to-reload-to-see-any-questions-for-a-search)

Comment: "*This is happening because, as your search gets larger, the query gets more and more complex, which results in longer loading times on the server.*" So the reason could be the number of tags that I have in the filter? Which makes the query larger thus slow response time?

Comment: That is _exactly_ the reason, yes.

Comment: I am an Oracle database application developer, so I understand the performance degradation of a huge query with too many `OR` conditions. That answers the question. Accepted!

Comment: @Michael `where q.tag in ('oracle', 'oraclefoo', 'oraclebar')` is internally interpreted by Oracle as `where q.tag = 'oracle' OR q.tag = 'oraclefoo' OR q.tag = 'oraclebar' ` No difference in terms of performance or the execution plan.